# Regexp wanted to format string of letters

Tags: regex

I want to format the initials of a persons name in a standard way. Every letter in the initials should be in uppercase and every letter (from to first until the last) must be followed by a dot. Like this:

```
JKP => J.K.P.
jkp => J.K.P.
J.KP => J.K.P.
JK.P => J.K.P.
JKP. => J.K.P.
J.K.P => J.K.P.
etc...
```

Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: which language ? This looks like a simple string manipulation job, you don't need a regex for this.

Comment: Not sure if a regex is the most intuitive way to solve the problem!

Comment: So Ludwig van Beethoven now gets the initials L.V.B.?

Comment: Everyone seems to be posting regular expressions :-).. Now you have two problems.

Answer (score 2):

As we do not know which language you are using here's some pseudo code that should do the job:

```
replace all dots in the string with ''
split the string into a character array
join the character array with a '.' and make it uppercase
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP equvalent:

```
$array = array (
'JKP',
'jkp',
'j.kp',
'jk.p',
'jkp.',
'j.k.p.',
);

foreach ($array as $s)
{
        echo strtoupper (preg_replace ('/(\w)\W*/', '\1.', $s)), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a java solution: `str.toUpperCase().replaceAll("(?<=\\w)(?!=\\.)", ".")`

Decoded, `(?<=\w)(?!=\.)` means *match between characters where the previous character is a word character and the next character is not a dot*

You should be able to adapt this regex to your language, whatever that is.

**EDITED:** To incorporate @Qtax suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl solution:

```
my @list = qw/JKP jkp J.KP JK.P JKP. J.K.P/;

for(@list){
    s/\w(?!\.)/$&./g;
    my $result = uc;
    print "$result\n";
}
```

`s/\w(?!\.)/$&./g` replaces all "word" chars not followed by a `.` with that char and a `.`, then just upper case it with `uc`.